# Apagar certificado do Certmgr pelo prompt de comando

Tags: windows, vba, cmd, excel-vba, prompt

preciso excluir determinados certificados do computador para que eles não atrapalhem meu um sistema de automatização do vba, porem não achei nada que possa me dar uma luz de como fazer isso por programação ou por linha de cmd. Atualmente estou utilizando o VBA para realizar a automação de alguns processo, alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer isso, de criar um processo, talvez, que consiga apagar estes certificados.
Hoje eu consigo apagar os certificados utilizando o Certmgr, entrando em Pessoal e depois em Certificados, ai excluo eles e o sistema roda perfeitamente, porem queria com que isso ficasse automático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de um tempo procurando a solução, eu achei este comando:

Detalhe importante: os certificados colocados no Windows ficam na seguinte pasta: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

Para excluir segue o seguinte código:

```
Shell ("cmd.exe /c cd C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates & del /a:s 'nomeCertificado'")
```

Com isso da para excluir os certificados antes de inserir o Token, por exemplo, e ao inserir ele o Windows automaticamente vai instalar o Token.